# Having trouble understanding generalized complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exterior-algebra

I'm reading a paper on the generalized complex numbers, but I have trouble in some of its fundamental properties. I have searched wiki but it left me none the wiser. Please see the image below, in which I have underlined the "dual numbers" with red because that's where I feel especially confused.
[image] 

My problems are:
1).The definition of the imaginary unit $i$ as $i^2=iq+p$ doesn't make me comfortable. Because I think it is a recursive one. Is there any other way to define $i$ equivalently but without recursion?
2).Why are all "dual numbers" located on the parabola: $p+\frac14q^2=0$? How to show it is equivalent to the definition "$i^2=0$"? I have tried to derive it but I come to nothing. I don't think it should be very hard but I just fail do it.
Could anyone give me some explanation or hint that is not beyond my limit? (I'm a freshman and so far I have learned a little elementary calculus and linear algebra) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a thought (and might not be applicable here), regarding (1) could you not use the quadratic formula to obtain a "non-recursive" definition, e.g. $$i=\frac{q\pm\sqrt{q^2-4p}}{2}.$$ You would probably need $q^2-4p\geq 0$, although I'm not too sure about that...

Comment: However The discriminant is not necessarily non negative. @pbs

Comment: @ Vim yes, as I said I'm not too sure about that part as I haven't looked into it a great deal. I think if the discriminant is negative then you still have a linear equation so you could still solve for $i$. My worry was that the $i$ resulting from the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ was a "different" $i$ from that being defined. But as I say I haven't looked into this in any depth whatsoever!

Comment: @pbs well I think your worry is reasonable. Because now $\sqrt {-1}$ is no longer the imaginary unit as we see in the traditional complex numbers.

Comment: @ Vim yes, that's exactly the problem I was thinking might arise.

Comment: There is no recursion. You might prefer defining the "imaginary unit" as a root of $x^2-qx-p$, just like $i$ is introduced as root of $x^2+0x+1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) The equation $i^2=iq+p$ is not a recursive definition. It is defined as a solution of a quadratic equation. It is just like our normal definition $i^2=-1$. In this definition you can solve $i$ to get the two solutions, just like when you "solve" $i^2=-1$, you get our ordinary definition of $i$.

2) This is to say, when you solve $i^2=iq+p$, i.e., $i^2-qi-p=0$, you get a repeated root when the discriminant is $0$. It is like the case $i^2=0$, where you have a repeated root $0$.

Comment: Thanks. But does that mean when the discriminant is not zero (like in the general cases) then $i$ is not unique?

Comment: When the discriminant is not zero, like in the case $i^2=-1$, we have then the pair of imaginary units, just like $\pm i$ in the ordinary case.

Comment: Sorry I still have some trouble here. First, why $i^2=0$ implies repeated roots 0? And, when $\Delta\ne0$, how to define $\sqrt 1$ and $\sqrt{-1}$ then?

Comment: The repeated root $0$ is like $(x-1)^2=0$ has a repeated root $1$. For the other case, like Henning Makholm pointed out, it is a vector space that is represented by a basis of two vectors. The dual number system seems very confusing to me too. But for the ordinary case, let me give you an example. If we let $i^2+i+1=0$, we are defining $i$ to be $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. So all complex numbers are represented by $x+iy$ where $i=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. I'm thinking that either the rest of the paper or the reference would give you some more explanation.

Answer (score 9):

I think the article you quote is using slightly facetious language in order to seem more interesting. In particular, when it seems to frame its question as "what are some other definitions of $i$?", it would be more honest to say

> What are the ways to define a *multiplication* operation on $\mathbb R^2$ which is compatible with normal vector *addition*, in a way such that there's a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ that behaves like $\mathbb R$ with its usual operations?

That's not as immediately attention-catching, of course. And it would still be implicit that they want the result, in particular to be a *commutative ring*. (Or better yet a *commutative unital $\mathbb R$-algebra*, but you probably don't know what that is, so just ignore that).

Once you have decided to answer this, a natural first step is to choose a coordinate system such that the subspace that behaves like $\mathbb R$ is the $x$-axis and $x\in\mathbb R$ corresponds to $(x,0)\in\mathbb R^2$. This fixes how our multiplication is going to behave on pairs of this form, and if we also want multiplication with the "real" subset to correspond to scalar multiplication of vectors, we're forced to define
$$ (x,0)\cdot(a,b)=(a,b)\cdot(x,0)=(ax,bx) $$

It now turns out that the only thing we still need to choose is what $(0,1)\cdot(0,1)$ will be. Once we've chosen $(0,1)\cdot(0,1)=(p,q)$, the associative and distributive laws forces the product of two arbitrary pairs to be
$$ (a,b)\cdot(c,d) = (ac+bdp, bdq+ad+bc) $$

The *complex numbers* result when we choose $(p,q)=(-1,0)$, and in that case we call the pair $(0,1)$ $i$. The authors of your article extends that naming to systems where $(p,q)\ne (-1,0)$, which is confusing and nonstandard if you ask me, but there you go.

It is still the case, as for the complex numbers that
$$ (a,b) = (a,0)+(0,b) = (a,0)+(b,0)\cdot(0,1) = a+bi $$
for all $a$ and $b$, but the rule for multiplying things differs from that of the complex numbers.

When the authors say $i^2=p+qi$, that's merely their notation for specifying  $(0,1)\cdot(0,1)=(p,q)$.

The point of the claim in Figure 1 is that there are only three fundamentally different choices for $(p,q)$, namely $(-1,0)$ (the complex numbers), $(0,0)$ (dual numbers), or $(1,0)$ (double numbers). For any *other* choice of $(p,q)$ the resulting number system turns out to be isomorphic to one of these three cases -- or in other words, it is *the same* as one of these three cases, just viewed through a different coordinate system (which by the authors' convention means that it's a *different* member of the ring that gets to be called $i$).

(It's a particularly confusing feature that Figure 1 shows the $p$ axis going *up*, when $p$ is the *real* part of "$i^2$", which ought to go *right* in the usual diagrams of the complex plane. The figure really ought to be flipped around the diagonal $p=q$).

Comment: So the isomorphism is the fact that all the generalised complex numbers are the same system under different coordinates just like one vector space under different bases?

Comment: @Vim: Almost right -- each of the "generalized complex" number systems is _one of the three_ canonical system, just under a different base.

Comment: Thank you four your explanation. It's brilliantly explicit!

Answer (score 4):

I think  the generalized complex number systems can simply be defined as rings of the form $\mathbb R[X]/(f(X))$ with $f(X)$ a real quadratic polynomial and $i$ is a notation of $\overline X$. For the meaning of this symbols maybe you can refer to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring).

Comment: Sorry but I haven't learned abstract algebra yet